# Google Sheets - Script to Change Currency Formatting Based On Dropdown Selection ($ + €)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, currency

I have a Sheet with two tabs — Tab 1 is a quote/invoice and Tab 2 is a list of clients. C3 on Tab 1 contains a dropdown list which pulls from Tab 2, Clients 1-4 use USD ($) but Client 5 uses EURO (€). Tab 1 also contains a costs column in I and a feeder column in H.

My goal is to use a script to change the currency formatting in column I based on what's selected in C3. When Client 5 is selected all costs in I need to contain a '€' prefix, and when anyone else is selected they need to contain a '$' prefix.

In the following code 'H' is a feeder cell where 'EURO' or '*literally anything else*' can be entered to change the currency format in 'I' between '€' to '$':

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheetName = "Main Sheet"; 
  var currencyCol = 8; //column H
  var amountCol = 9; //column I
  var defaultFormat = "[$$]#,##0.00";
  var currencyFormat = {"USD":"[$$]#,##0.00",
                        "EURO":"[$€]#,##0.00"};
  var r = e.range;
  if(e.source.getSheetName()==sheetName && r.getColumn() == currencyCol){ // This assumes I want to manually change H, I'd rather have it automatically change between EURO (including € in column I) when client 5 is selected, and USD (including $ in column I) when clients 1-4 are selected
    var uf = currencyFormat[r.getValue()];
    uf = uf?uf:defaultFormat;
    r.offset(0,amountCol-currencyCol).setNumberFormat(uf);
  }
}
```

It works, but I have to manually type 'EURO' or '*anything else*' in 'H' line-by-line to change the currencies for 'I' - but I need it to change automatically based on the selection in C3.

I tried using =if(C3="Client 5", "EURO", "") in Column H which works the first time Client 5 is selected in the dropdown, but doesn't reset 'I' to '$' once changed and needs to be manually typed in before working again.

I also tried 2 Macros which manually input 'EURO' and 'USD' into column H and tried to run them with a script to trigger when Client 5 is selected. It worked in 'H', but 'I' didn't change when the words appeared I think the issue is that the code isn't/can't trigger outside of manual data entry.

Any help would be great, I'm a beginner and I can't wrap my head around it. Feel free to message me or ask for a link to a test sheet.

Also I attached a screenshot of what tab 1 & 2 look like. I manually changed EURO to USD on Tab 1 to set that currency in column I, ideally that change can be based off C3[Spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAmu1.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike All good, thanks for responding! I'm looking to change the currency format in Column 'I' based on what is selected from a dropdown menu in cell C3. Clients 1 through 4 in that dropdown use USD ('$') as their currency, but Client 5 uses EURO ('€'). Depending on which option is selected, I need Column 'I' to reflect one of those currencies accurately. The code in my post properly changes the currency prefix in Column I if I type it in manually, but I need it to work automatically based on the selection in C3. Let me know if that clarifies anything!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, how do you want to do about the column "H" in "Tab1"? And, in your script, `"USD":"[$$]#,##0.00"` and `"EURO":"[$€]#,##0.00"` are used. But, in your image, "DOLLAR" and "EURO" are used. In your expected result, what do you want to use about this?

Comment: By guessing your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a dropdown list of "C3" of "Tab1" sheet is changed, you want to change the number format of the cells "I8:I".
- You want to retrieve the values of the dropdown list and the corresponding number formats from the cells "B4:C8" of "Tab2".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName1 = "Tab1"; // Please set the sheet name of "Tab1".
  var sheetName2 = "Tab2"; // Please set the sheet name of "Tab2".
  var r = e.range;
  if (e.source.getSheetName() == sheetName1 && r.getA1Notation() == "C3") {
    var defaultFormat = "[$$]#,##0.00";
    var currencyFormat = { "DOLLAR": "[$$]#,##0.00", "EURO": "[$€]#,##0.00" };
    var obj = e.source.getSheetByName(sheetName2).getRange("B2:C8").getValues().reduce((o, [b, c]) => (o[b] = c, o), {});
    var sheet = r.getSheet();
    sheet.getRange("I8:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).setNumberFormat(currencyFormat[obj[e.value]] || defaultFormat);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when the dropdown list of "C3" of "Tab1" sheet is changed, the number format of cells "I8:I" is changed by the values of "B4:C8" of "Tab2". In this case, the column "H" is not used. Please be careful about this.
- In your script, `"USD":"[$$]#,##0.00"` and `"EURO":"[$€]#,##0.00"` are used. But, in your image, "DOLLAR" and "EURO" are used. In this modification, "DOLLAR" and "EURO" are used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)